# Next Prev buttons over UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I am having trouble with layout in Interface Builder (Xcode 9 / iOS 11).

I have a UIScrollview and over it I have 2 buttons (next and prev view).
If I put the buttons under the scroll view, they appear and work. But if I put them over the scroll view, they don't appear anymore.

What can be the problem?

Layout buttons and scrollview:

[image: Layout buttons and scrollview]

Warning message:

[image: Warning message]

[Drag scrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvChd.png)
[Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOJFs.png)

Comment: Do you want the Prev/Next buttons to *move* when you drag (scroll) the content of your scroll view? Or do you want them to stay in position, while the content scrolls *behind* the buttons?

Comment: I want buttons stay in position while the content scrolls behind the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand first how `UIScrollView` works. Check again the Warning Message. It says:

> ScrollView has ambiguous scrollable content

It means that the subviews of your scrollView does not have enough constraints attached to them and to the scrollView to make the scrollView scroll. Well how does the scrollView scroll? If the content of the scrollView exceeds the frame (either width or height) of the scrollView, then the scrollView will be scrollable.

In your problem, the two buttons do not push each other to the scrollView's frame, is this clear? It means your buttons do not have enough constraints.

I'll try to provide an example in a bit.

Comment: I put constraints to scrollview and also for the buttons, and still no help, but when i tryed to drag on scroll view i saw next button attached, but i don't know why is there.

Answer (score 0):

When working in Interface Builder, if you drag and drop one object onto a container object - such as a `UIView` or `UIScrollView` (which is also a `UIView`), the object will become a *subview* of the container.

That makes it a little difficult to do what you want, which is to have the buttons *on top of* the scroll view, ***NOT*** as subviews of the scroll view.

As you see in this image, the buttons are clearly NOT subviews of the scroll view:

[image]

In this image, I drag/drop the buttons onto the scroll view, and they become *subviews*:

[image]

So, to get what you want, add the buttons *outside* of the scroll view and set their constraints. I gave `Prev` a leading constraint of `16` and `Next` a trailing constraint of `16`... both constrained to the *view*, not the scroll view. Then I constrained `Next` to be centered-vertically to `Prev` so they will stay vertically aligned to each other.

**Then** give `Prev` a centered-vertically constraint to the scroll view. Select `Editor -> Update Frames` and the buttons will move into position, but - as you can see from the Document Outline - they are *not* subviews of the scroll view:

[image]

At this point, you can drag-scroll any content you add as *subviews* of the scroll view (such as the image view here) without affecting the buttons:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for demonstration!

Comment: In Xcode 11, it is no longer difficult. Please refer to my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want your buttons *over* (and not *under*) the scroll view. That's easy enough in Xcode 11 Interface Builder, which lets you pin subviews of scroll view (i.e., its content view(s)) to either the Frame Layout Guide or the Content Layout Guide or a combination of either.

The frame layout guide defines the size of the visible area of the content view by applying width and height constraints based on any superview other than the scroll view or its container (in other words, another sibling subview to the parent view containing the scrollview).

The content layout guide defines the size of the overall area of the content view any applying width and height constraints of based on same, which is, or course, larger than the frame of the scroll view:

[image: The Content Layout Guide, selected in Xcode 11 Interface Builder, provides the intrinsic size constraints required by a scrollview]

Using these layout guides obviate the need to toggle scrolling in either direction; constraining the Content Layout Guide to a height or width of the visible frame of the scrollview determines whether it can be scrolled vertically or horizontally.

That means that, if you constrain a subview of the scrollview to the Frame Layout Guide, it will not scroll (and, yet, will be a true subview of the scrollview).

The

> Frame and Content Layout Guides added to the UIScrollView Interface
>   Builder component in Xcode 11 is not yet documented; however, Apple
>   still distributes [an out-dated document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html) that describes how to create > a "floating view" in a scroll view with Xcode 10 or earlier.